# send command from java to linux

Tags: java, linux, runtime

i want to send below command from java to linux

FAXSERVER=ttyIAX3@127.0.0.1

this command changes the modem of hylafax for send fax
and this command runs successfully in linux shell
but when it runs from java as follows:

```
modemcommand = "FAXSERVER=ttyIAX3@127.0.0.1";
    InputStreamReader isr = null;

    try {

        isr = new InputStreamReader(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(modemcommand).getInputStream());

        System.out.println("The Command : "+modemcommand+" is running successfull!"); 
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("The Command : "+modemcommand+" is not running successfull!"); 
        System.out.println("Error on switch to modem : "+Modem+" :--> "+ex.toString());
        System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------");

    }
```

output is: error=2 :no such file or directory
Can someone help me?

Comment: This only a command when interpreted by some shell, so you rather mean something like `sh FAXSERVER=...`; but this is perhaps still not the cure for your problem, as the environment variable is scoped to the shells process (no such thing as a global setting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting an environment variable called `FAXSERVER` to the value `ttyIAX3@127.0.0.1` but you don't supply the name of the command to execute. Use something like

```
modemcommand = "FAXSERVER=ttyIAX3@127.0.0.1 my_command";
```

Comment: There is no command. You are only setting an environment variable for the shell command that never comes.